# Can I use packagemanager.setApplicationEnabledSetting() on non-rooted device in user app

Tags: android, security, app-launcher

I am trying to disable one of the app from my app. I have created a launcher app and trying to use following method of package manager

pm.setApplicationEnabledSetting(packageInfo.packageName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

But I'm getting SecurityException as
SecurityException: Permission Denial: attempt to change component state from pid=20217, uid=10066, package uid=10067

**Note:** Somewhere I found the solution to this is to mention below permission in manifest

But I'm getting a warning in this permission that this permission is only granted to system apps.

Comment: "I am trying to disable one of the app from my app" -- why? "But I'm getting a warning in this permission that this permission is only granted to system apps" -- correct. Otherwise, malware authors would readily disable all sorts of apps, as part of a ransomware attacks.

Comment: Yes you are right. But then what is the correct way to change the component state?

Comment: You don't change the component state. You do something else. Since you did not bother to answer the "why?" question from my original comment, I have no way to advise you as to possible alternatives.

Comment: "I am trying to disable one of the app from my app" -- why? - The purpose for creating such app is to achieve mobile device management through launcher app.My app is only for particular organization.

Comment: If you are truly implementing an MDM solution, you are welcome to look at the device admin and device owner APIs.

Comment: Can we run such apps(device owner) on avd? Because I was not able to encrypt my device (avd). Also I want to know whether it is required to create profile if we have created device owner app?

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable/enable other apps your app must have system privileges. To achieve privileges you should do these steps.

Add this line to your manifest header **android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"**

Add this permission to the manifest  **"android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE"**

**Sign your app with a system key.**

I checked it in my launcher app.